# Django Variable Used In Model And View

Tags: django

I can find plenty of information on global variables (though I know they should be avoided so am trying to find alternatives) and sharing variables between views, though my case is a little different.

At the moment I have the same variable declared in two places, one in a class in `models.py` (it's fired when a `model` is created but it's not a model declaration), and it's also passed to a template through a `view`.

What would be my best option for storing this variable? Should it be a global or is there a better alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are asking about your ***attempted solution*** rather than your ***actual problem***.

Comment: I guess so yes, I am going to use a global variable unless I can find a better alternative

Comment: What is your ***actual problem***?

Comment: I have a variable that's needed by my ```models.py``` (in a helper class, not in a model declaration), and its also used in my ```view.py```. Is there a better alternative to creating a global variable or repeating the same code (```number_of_classes=4```)?

Comment: This "global" variable is a count of rows?

Comment: It's the number of lessons a certain unit has. When a student enrolls in a unit, the class in ```models.py``` creates an object for each lesson and attaches it to the user. So if the user enrolls in unit 1, it has 5 lessons, so 5 ```lesson_data``` objects are created and attached to the student. In my template I have a loop that displays all the units and data related to each lesson. It needs to know how many times to iterate through the loop so I use a variable ```number_of_lessons```.

Comment: @Brenden you need to create a queryset that contains all lessons for a student and iterate over that, you don't need a global variable

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll give that a go. I appreciate it.